# Is there a limit on .class file name lengths in google app engine, outside of jar files?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting errors when I attempt to run my project deployed to app engine.  I see issues like:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seattleglassware.AuthServletSupport$$anonfun$finishOAuth2Dance$1$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$apply$37$$anonfun$apply$40$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42$$anonfun$apply$45$$anonfun$apply$47$$anonfun$apply$48$$anonfun$apply$49
```

The class name looks reasonable (well, for certain values of reasonable - this is code generated by the Scala compiler).  I see the file in my local web/WEB-INF/classes/com directory and I can decompile it with javap (so I don't think it's corrupt or anything silly like that.)  Everything works fine running on a local debug server.

Even more strange, I can pour all the .class files in web/WEB-INF/classes into a jar file like this:

```
cd to the web/WEB-INF/classes directory
jar cf ../lib/classes.jar .
```

And now, if I upload the project (pressing the deploy button in Eclipse), I don't see those ClassNotFoundException errors.  Delete the jar file, re-upload the project, get the errors again.

I'm wondering if there's some sort of limit on the names of .class files?  Or something else happening in the deployment process that's causing this to happen?

EDIT: running from the command line made this much more clear (using maven now):

> SEVERE: Invalid character in filename: WEB-INF/classes/com/seattleglassware/AuthServletSupport$$anonfun$finishOAuth2Dance$1$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$apply$37$$anonfun$apply$40$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42$$anonfun$apply$45$$anonfun$apply$47$$anonfun$apply$48$$anonfun$apply$49.class

But it still looks to me like that's a valid filename.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of "special" characters in the file name may be the issue here.

There is currently an open issue regarding "special" characters in project file names.

[Issue 2211: Special characters are not supported in the filenames in the project](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2211)

The original issue was reported by a Python App Engine user, however if you look in the comments you'll see that it apparently affects Java users as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing special in the names.